# How to have a dialog box for save as to save a xml file from server, on client side

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently It just opens up the xml, but i want to get a dialog box to ask the client whether to save/open. I am using jquery

```
$('#btnDownloadConfig').click(function(event){
    var location="/csm"+path;
    window.open(location);
/*it opens up a new window having url "http://incsm:8181/csm/files/12345/csmclient.xml*/
});
```

My path on Server

```
E:\Tomcat 6\webapps\csm\files\12345
```

the above path contains `csmclient.xml` file, how can i make a dialog box appear asking to save/open for this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible. If you want the browser to prompt the user to download a file that it would usually render then you must send a Content-Disposition header (marking the file as an attachment) from the server. There is nothing you can do client side.

Comment: I saw it in chrome, that a small dialog appears with save option (without the explore option), Isn't that too possible?

Comment: Nothing you can do client side (short of using Ajax and doing everything yourself (and that won't let you save files)) can change the way a browser will handle a file.